# Is there any other way than making 850+ UPDATE statements?

Tags: oracle, vba, excel, oracle11g

I'm making some stuff in Excel VBA, where i need to read around 850 or more lines from an excel sheet and update them in an existing table in oracle 11g. Luckly it's just 2 columns that interest me.

The only way i'm currently doing the thing is just looping through the Range in excel and create a single `UPDATE myTable SET Temp = Array(i, 2) WHERE id = Array(i,1)` for each field in the array.

Now... i'm quite aware that this isn't neiter fast, nor elegant, and that is why i'm looking for tips and tricks to optimize such a thing.

I am very thankful for every tip provided.

===UPDATE===

After testing Kacpers suggestion by making temporary tables the result is that when using an excel where i have interest in 2 columns (about 850 rows) it takes about 2 minutes to read the data and write it into the table using an `INSERT ALL`method with 850 inserts.
The other table and excel file have about 970 lines and 3 columns, whereas filtered out i write about 700 lines and stll uses about a minute to complete.

The last part is combining with the existing table, whereas the process before this implementation took around 35 seconds, now takes 45-55 seconds.

This still seems like a pretty slow method. Especially the insertion part.
Like i told in the comments i do not have access to the server storage system so uploading or making a CSV to import data is not an option.

Would still very much appreciate any tips or hints i could use to optimize the procedure.

Comment: Here is one of the options. Save Excel file as CSV file and create [external table](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/et_concepts.htm) on that file.

Comment: Hi, as far as i know that would require me to have access to the filesystem on which the Oracle database is hosted. I do not have those rights and asking for them each time i'd wish to update the tables.

Comment: Yes, it would require you to have access to the server oracle installed on. Here is another option then involving  Oracle SQL Developer. Create a table corresponding to the  layout(number and datatype of the columns) of your excel file. RMB(right mouse button) click on that table and choose "import data".

Comment: Ah you see, the excel file is updated every now and then by a third party and the user should always be able to have access to the freshest data automatically/via the excel macro, so such an approach does not provide the solution i am looking for.

Comment: Dou you have an index on column `id`? Inserts should be much faster, is there any trigger which slows down the insert?

Comment: No, these are two basic tables with no index and no triggers. Do you think putting an index on the "id" would make it faster?

Comment: Yes of course it should be faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so i have used half of a solution that Kacper suggested, meaning i introduced a temporary table, which i have filled up firstly using ~850 INSERTs in the matter of:
`INSERT ALL INSERT ... END` However the solution took about 1-2 minutes to execute.

Another topic suggested i "concatenate" my data into a single insert command and execute it only once.
That seemed to be the most efficient method, so my insert currently looks like:

```
INSERT INTO myTempTable (id, temp) SELECT 'data1', 'data2' from dual
UNION ALL SELECT 'data3', 'data4' from dual
UNION ALL SELECT 'data5', 'data6' from dual
...
```

Resulting in taking only about a second to perform all 850 inserts and prolonging the update of `myTable` by joining for only about 5 seconds in average.

Thank you all for participating and ll the helpfull tips you have provided!

Answer (score 1):

First please either import your excel to table or create external table based on csv data from xls file. Lets say you imported data to table t1 with columns c1, c2

Then you can perform merge operation:

```
merge into myTable mt
using t1
on (mt.id = t1.c1)
when matched then update set
Temp = c2;
```

here you can additionally put `when not matched then insert` if you need to insert rows that not exist in myTable;

Comment: Does such an approach require me to upload a .CSV file for importation ionto the Oracle host? if yes, i sadly have no access to it.

Comment: No, but it require you to create a table in database and fill it with data from file, for example by import via sqldeveloper.

Comment: Using SQL developer isn't a viable option. The point of the Excel/VBA is to provide a solution without needing additional external tools. However... I presume there is another fast way to do multiple inserts into a table without additional tools? If yes, that would also be a good option. And then a merge.

Comment: Of course you can easily generate insert script from excel file. It will be something like insert into t1 values (Array(i, 1),Array(i, 2)).;

Comment: Currently inserting from one excel file with around 850 lines and two attributes takes 2 minutes, the other file and table with 3 attributes and 700 entries takes another 1 minute. Still quite slow, as the whole procedure then lasts about 4-5 mins. Too long...

Answer (score 1):

You should use prepared statements with bind variables like this (not tested):

```
Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set cmd.ActiveConnection = con ' your "ADODB.Connection" object
cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE myTable SET Temp = ? WHERE id = ?"    
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("newVal", adVarChar, adParamInput, 10)
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("id", adBigInt, adParamInput)

con.BeginTrans
For i = 1 To 850
   cmd.Parameters("newVal").Value = Array(i, 2)
   cmd.Parameters("id").Value = Array(i, 1)
   cmd.Execute
Next
con.CommitTrans
```

Important: `cmd.Parameters.Append` must be done only once outside the loop. Otherwise you will not gain anything.

Most likely it will be not as fast as an Direct-Path INSERT (e.i. an external table) but performance should be sufficient.

Comment: This looks quite promising, Could i ask for a definition of that cmd in VBA?

Comment: As i have updated my question with some results (which i'm not satisfied with) this optin is currently the only one ramining. As you seem to cooment that it's slower than using Inserts, should i even give it a try? Or will if profit nothing?

Comment: Is is faster when you put the command in a transaction? By default each command is commited which slows down the process.

Comment: Wernfried Domscheit i have not yet tried doing it as a transaction. Any examples for a newbie?